# jQueryMobile - How to combine internal page and normal page swipes?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to navigate internal jqueryMobile pages (data-page="mypage") and normal ones (xxxx.php) in the same solution. I want it to behave as it follows:

- from #lista-x perform a swipe to right and go to #listas
- from #listas perform a new swipe to right and go to index.php

The problem is that if I perform a swipe at #lista-x it goes directly to the index.php. I barely see that it is performing both actions, that is, first it goes to #listas and then to index.php.
This is my code (it is simplified in order to let you understand it easier):

```
 <!-- EXAMPLE.PHP -->
    <div data-role="page" id="listas">
            <a data-role="button" href="#lista-1">lista 1</a>
            <a data-role="button" href="#lista-2">lista 2</a>
            <a data-role="button" href="#lista-3">lista 3</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="lista-1">
            //something...
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="lista-2">
            //something...
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="lista-3">
            //something...
        </div>


<script type="text/javascript">    
$("[id='listas']").bind('pageshow', function(){
    // Gestos táctiles
            $(function() {
                $("body").bind('swiperight', function(event) {
                        window.location = "mov-eventos.php";
                        // $.mobile.changePage( "mov-eventos.php");
                });

            });
    });


    $("[id^='lista-']").bind('pageshow', function(){
    // Gestos táctiles
        $(function() {
            $("body").bind('swiperight', function(event) {
                    $.mobile.changePage("#listas", "slide", false, true);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I solve it in order to behave as I have explained before?:

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that although you're selecting only some elements (for example `$("[id^='lista-']")`), you're binding the `swiperight` event to the body element, so the `swiperight` is fired twice. You've to bind it to the selected elements.